# Are there any possible complications from seeding a PRNG with the machine's stack pointer?

Tags: assembly, random, x86, cpu-registers

I have a cursory understanding of low-level programming and the x86 architecture.  As I understand it the value at the current stack pointer (`SP`, `ESP` or `RSP` on Intel machines) is unpredictable and since it's very likely to change several times within a single second, it strikes me as a better unpredictable seed than the current system time (which is normally in seconds).

Eg:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT, STDCALL
.DATA
    fmt db "%d", 10, 0
.CODE
INCLUDELIB MSVCRT
EXTERN printf:PROC
EXTERN rand:PROC
EXTERN srand:PROC
_main PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push esp
    call srand
    add esp, 4

    mov ecx, 10

l1:
    push ecx
    call rand
    push eax
    push offset fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    pop ecx
    loop l1

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    add esp, 4
    jmp dword ptr [esp-4]
_main ENDP
END
```

The output of this program varies even when the same program is executed multiple times in one second.

However, I figured that since I'm most likely *not* the first person on the planet to have thought of this idea, if there are any potential pitfalls or disasters that I am risking by doing it this way - as I said before, I'm just now learning about assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the fundamental assumption that the stack pointer will not remain constant is a reasonable one, there are several main issues with using it as a random number generator:

First of all - when you are in the same level within a program (for example, 4 functions in) - the stack pointer will remain pretty much constant. For example, if I go from main to proc1 to proc2, then each time I enter proc1 I will push 5 items to the stack, and every time I leave proc1 I will pop out 7 items from the stack. In the end, whenever I enter proc1, my stack pointer is pretty much in the same place. This is bad in the case of a random number generator because if you call it a bunch of times you will generally call it in the same depth and hence approximately the same stack pointer. This isn't an issue if you're using it in a recursive function, but that's pretty limiting.

Second - although the stack pointer does change, it doesn't change by that much. Good randomness means not only a good random function but also a good seed - high-level / cryptographic systems can and often do have their entropy 'depleted'. In a sense, between two consecutive runs of the random function, your stack pointer only changes by about 0x10 to 0x40 bytes, which isn't remotely enough for good randomness.

Finally - the starting size of the stack has a massive effect on the program output. Whether the stack starts at size 0x1000 or Whether it starts at size 0x3000 will have a significant change on the output, because the input values will generally hover around that starting value (assuming your programs aren't particularly huge), making it the primary source of randomness in the process.

Randomness in assembly is hard but this isn't the solution

Answer (score 1):

The [Time Stamp Counter](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ics/itac/81/ITC_Reference_Guide/CPU_Cycle_Counter_%28TSC%29.htm) advances very fast, while the stack pointer (and other registers) will probably use a few addresses over the run of the program (essentially, one for each possible call chain leading to your seeder function, probably just one).

What do you need the PRNG for? On Linux there are the random devices, specifically for such uses. AFAIU, the BSD Unices have something similar. For simulations or testing it is useful to be able to repeat the secuence; for e.g. a game seeding with the current time of the TSC should be plenty.